# Async lambda expressions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda, async-await

Async `Sub` like this:

```
Dim f As Func(Of Task) = Async Sub()
                         End Sub
```

Produces compiler error:

> **error BC36670:** Nested sub does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of System.Threading.Tasks.Task)'.

Equivalent C# code compiles fine:

```
Func<Task> f = async () => { };
```

Rewriting `Async Sub` into `Async Function` make code works.

Why does `Async Sub()` is not convertible to delegate types with return value of type `Task`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET `Sub` is equivalent to C# returning `void`. There's a difference between `async void Foo() {}` and `async Task Foo() {}`, and your VB.NET is doing the former, while you want the latter. As you mention, `Async Function` makes it work, because then it actually does the latter.

Edit: some more details:

C#:

```
async void Foo() { }

async Task Bar() { }

void Baz()
{
    object dummy;
    dummy = (Action) Foo; // OK
    dummy = (Func<Task>) Foo; // error
    dummy = (Action) Bar; // error
    dummy = (Func<Task>) Bar; // OK
}
```

However, this gets a bit more confusing when delegates are used, because the delegate equivalents of `Foo` and `Bar` look the same: `async () => { }`.

The only difference is that in VB.NET, the delegates do not look the same, because the `Sub` or `Function` keyword remains part of the syntax there.

Comment: VB.NET `Function` actually means that some value will be returned from method. There is no return value in the code above, so lambda-`Function` actually should be lambda-`Sub`. Do you ever see `Function` without `Return` statement in VB.NET?

Comment: @ControlFlow The C# equivalent does return a value, and that value is a `Task`. The return of that task is implicit: you don't have a `return` statement, but you do return something. It's the same in VB.NET.

Comment: @hvd I think the question is that while the C# `async` keyword acts to convert the declaration of a `void` function into a `Func<Task>`, in VB.NET `Async` appears **not** to convert the declaration of a `Sub` into the same thing. Note that in the C# example, we can take `() => {}` (which doesn't return anything, and so corresponds to a VB.NET `Sub`) and assign it to a `Func<Task>` simply by prepending `async` - the analogous process appears *not* to work in VB.NET. I think that's the question, anyway.

Comment: @AakashM The C# `async` keyword doesn't do that. The C# example creates a function returning a `Task`, which is assignable to a `Func<Task>`. The C# example doesn't have anything returning `void`. I'll expand in my answer.

Comment: So it's the case (for both languages) that when using `async`/`Async`, you need to *declare* things as functions and then explicitly *not* return anything? (eg your `Bar` declaration looks like it shouldn't compile!) ((disclaimer: not played with async yet!))

Comment: @AakashM Yes, exactly. And in async functions returning `Task<T>`, you don't return a `Task<T>`, you return a `T`: `async Task<int> Foo() { return 1; }`

Comment: @AakashM: Think about enumerators in C#: when you say `IEnumerable<int> M() { yield return 1; }` you *return* nothing, and you *yield* an integer. You do not return a sequence of integers -- you return nothing -- and you do not yield a sequence of integers -- you yield an integer. The compiler takes care of the rewrite into a method that returns `IEnumerable<int>`. Async methods are the same way. If the async method returns a `Task<int>` then you *return* an int, and the compiler turns that into a method that returns a `Task<int>`.